# posting into wordpress from postman works, but from my application it doesn't

Tags: c#, wordpress, restsharp

If I use postman to call into a wordpress site using OAuth 1.0 and just supply the consumer key and consumer secret it works.

From my application which is running in IIS I have the following code (i'm using Restsharp):

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(my https end point)
                {
                    Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(my consumer key, my consumer secret, "", "")
                    
                };
            
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddJsonBody(serializedData);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");

            var response = await Task.Run(() => client.Execute(request));
```

when I run this, I receive :

> " Content:
> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you
> are not allowed to create resources.","data":{"status":401}}"

has anybody any ideas why it works from postman but not from my code.

Addendeum: re @Buttered_toast comment.

Postman shows:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_a22ad9ddea2d9fe71d9178c419ea51b4dc93a6db&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1626693986&oauth_nonce=DpuZJkki4ls&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=KWOlTkd252IE0%2F6TyZsz02doot8%3E");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "shopmagic_visitor_ac4663521b1f6dee163a6e79e3fb5bed=%7B%22meta%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22user_id%22%3A66852%2C%22hash%22%3A%22aaddd576aba79174df9fecf33c34a30e%22%7D; wp_automatewoo_visitor_ac4663521b1f6dee163a6e79e3fb5bed=z5kof9imdkp0o2avar92");
```

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the code postman produces?, postman has a code option for many languages, try using that first and if it works, change it accordingly.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Hi, I cant see where to get that from

Comment: Look for `</>` in the top right of the postman panel

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I see in there there is a RestSharp option. Selecting that I can see a Cookie has been added the the Header.  I'm guessing though that this is injected into the request from the site i'm trying to call by the look of things. There is also an oauth_nonce  that I'm not setting, it could be that, but I've not seen how to add that onto the restsharp object i.e. my `var client`